# Cannot read property 'codeGen' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot

I was preparing new Angular2 Project by Angular-CLI. There is no problem when I build app in the sipmlest way:

```
ng build
```

but if I i try build my app with *--aot* parameter i get this error:

> ERROR in Cannot read property 'codeGen' of undefined
>
> ERROR in ./src/main.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'D:\GRMCloud\grm-cloud\src' 
>   @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74  @ multi main

It's a empty Angular2 project there are no my changes. 
Anyone can help me?
Anyone?

Comment: you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: From what I remember I had to downgrade angular and typesript libraries in my package.json. Maybe this link will help you https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4551